# Getting value from iframe working in IE but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am using lwip tcp/ip stack with a STM32F4 to host a small configuration website for my device. I am refreshing a hidden iframe on my page to get updated SSI values and then using them in my *tmp* variable to update a graph. The code below works great in IE but in Firefox and Chrome *tmp* only gets a value once even though the *temptemp* element is getting updated values from my firmware.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID");
var innerdoc = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
if(innerdoc.document)innerdoc = innerdoc.document;
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.shtml', 
    complete: function() {
      document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.location.reload();
      setTimeout(worker, 1000);
      tmp = innerdoc.getElementById("temptemp").value;
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

"*Domains, protocols and ports must match.*"

Have you checked the console for errors, when running this in Firefox and Chrome? I think you're being told that you cannot access unsafe JavaScript. Perhaps Internet Explorer is just fine with being insecure about how it runs JavaScript.

Comment: Yes the code does give errors in IE now that I think about it. That must be why it does not work in Chrome. As to why it doesn't work, I am unsure.

Comment: IE is more lax about this, though not all the time. Why it doesn't work? Either the domains don't match, the protocols don't match, or the ports don't match. The `<iframe>` needs to come from the same origin (domain), using the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS), and operate on the same port.